# regionprops orientation behaves differently with logical and integers

Tags: matlab

It seems that regionprops 'orientation' behaves differentlty if we give a logical or an integer :

```
A = [ 0 0 0 1 1 0 ;
    0 0 0 1 0 0 ;
    1 1 0 0 0 0 ;
    0 0 0 0 0 0 ; 
    0 0 0 0 1 0 ;
    0 0 0 0 0 0 ]

a_orientation = regionprops(A,'Orientation')

% Orientation: 28.1550

B = logical(A)

b_orientation = regionprops(B,'Orientation')

% 3x1 struct array with fields:
%     Orientation

b_orientation.Orientation

% ans =
%      0
% 
% ans =
%    45.0000
% 
% ans =
%      0
%
```

How could I make regionprops behave with logical the same way as with integers without changing the type ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can't you just use something like `b_orientation = regionprops(double(B),'Orientation')`? Or `b_orientation = regionprops(uint8(B),'Orientation')` if memory is of concern. Anyway, the difference seems to arise because with logical input `regionprops` _computes_ connected components among the `true` values, whereas with numbers it interprets each number as _already_ defining a component. Compare `a_orientation = regionprops(A,'Area')` and `a_orientation = regionprops(B,'Area')`

Comment: It is the same for regionprops 'Area'. I know I could use what you suggest, but my wish is to understand why regionprops behaves like this.

Comment: Your question was _how to avoid that_, not _why it happens_. The _why_ is what I stated in my comment. 
gnovice has provided a better explanation in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass `A` (a double precision matrix) into [`regionprops`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html), it is treated as a [label matrix](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html#inputarg_L) with only one labeled region corresponding to the ones. It essentially assumes the data you are giving to it is the output from [`bwlabel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html). The metrics are computed across all the pixels labeled 1.

When you pass `B` (a logical matrix), it is treated as a [binary image](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html#inputarg_BW), in which there are three distinct regions of ones (i.e. 8-connected components) found. Metrics are returned for each region.

I don't believe there is any way to get `regionprops` to treat a logical input differently without first converting its type. Logical inputs appear to always undergo a connected-component processing step that identifies each "island" of ones as separate regions to analyze.